# Is there any way I can install Windows games on Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, windows, games

I recently switched to Linux from Windows and really like Ubuntu but I have alot of Windows games I can't play anymore.

Answer (score 1):

### Free solution

There are several ways to run Windows games on Ubuntu. You could try [Play On Linux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/), which is a front end of Wine. It is more user friendly to install a good number of windows games on Ubuntu.

Not only Play On Linux, you could also try [Stream](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/steam-launcher/). Recently, Valve games released a native Ubuntu client of Stream. This'll help you to play a lot of popular windows games on Ubuntu.

Lastly, you can also try Wine separately. To get a detailed list of supported games by Wine [click here](http://appdb.winehq.org/)

And importantly, you can install all these applications from Ubuntu Software Center, along with using commands in Terminal.

### Paid solution

Along with free solution you can also choose paid solution, if you want. [Crossover Linux](http://www.codeweavers.com/) is very good paid solution. They have different type of packages with professional support.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, [WINE](http://www.winehq.org/) is a very good option. Besides opening the terminal and running `sudo apt-get install wine`, you can also find it by searching for WINE in the Ubuntu Software Center (I know every user isn't comfortable venturing into the terminal, and I don't want you to think you *have* to use it if you don't want to).

WINE works very well for most programs, but some may require some tinkering in the WINE configuration to get things set up just right.  In my experience older programs are more likely to run without issue than newer programs are, but there are plenty of exceptions in both of those categories.

For a database of software that works in WINE, along with ratings of how well the software works, you can look at the [official site here](http://appdb.winehq.org/).

---

If you are willing to pay money for additional convenience, there is also a program called [CrossOver](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/), released by CodeWeavers. CrossOver is built on top of and using WINE, and CodeWeavers is the largest contributor to the WINE project, so while CodeWeavers does make money off of your purchase, at least some of the purchase price goes back into development of WINE.

There is a free trial of CrossOver available in the Software Center that will work for 15 days, if you would like to give both WINE and CrossOver a try and see which meets your needs better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Wine.  To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below.

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

For more information on Wine Click [Here](http://www.winehq.org/)